On an generalized integral of Ramanujan's $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}}{1+x}\cdot\frac{(1+ax)\cdots (1+ax q^{n-1})}{(1+x) \cdots (1+x q^n)}\, dx$
In a paper by Ramanujan: Messenger of Mathematics, XLIV, 1915, 10 – 18
He stated the formula (on page 72) $$\int_0^{\infty}x^{n-1}\frac{(1+arx)(1+ar^2x)(1+ar^3 x)\cdots}{(1+x)(1+rx)(1+r^2 x)\cdots}\, dx =\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi n } \left\{\prod_{m\geq 1}\frac{(1-r^{m-n})(1-ar^m)}{(1-r^m)(1-a r^{m-n})}\right\}$$
for $0<r<1$, $n>0$ and $0<a<r^{n-1}$ (I suspect the formula is also valid for $|r|<1, \Re(r)>0$. I'll come back to this later).

I am now considering the closed form of a finite version $$I_n(a)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{1+x}\left(\frac{(1+ax)\cdots (1+ax q^{n-1})}{(1+qx) \cdots (1+x q^n)}\right)\, dx \tag{1}$$
My attempt is the following. Let $\displaystyle f_n(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)(1+qx)\cdots(1+q^{n-1}x)}$ and $g_n(x)=(1+ax)(1+aqx)\cdots (1+a q^{n-2} x)$. I noticed that
$$(1-q^n)f_{n+1}(x)=f_n(x)-q^nf_n(xq)\tag{2} $$
$$g_{n+1}(xq)-q^n g_{n+1}(x)=(1-q^n)g_{n}(xq) \tag{3}$$
Multiplying $(2)$ and $(3)$, multiplying both sides by $x^{s-1}$, integrating on $0<x<\infty$ and with $\Re(q)>0$ we have
$$I_n(aq)-I_{n-1}(aq)=q^n\left\{I_n(a)-q^{-s} I_{n-1}(a)\right\} \tag{4}$$
The $a=0$ case reduces to a simple relation and gives $$I_n(0)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{(1+x)(1+xq)\cdots(1+xq^n)}\, dx = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi s}\left\{\frac{(1-q^{1-s})(1-q^{2-s})\cdots(1-q^{n-s})}{(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots(1-q^n)}\right\} $$

From Ramanujan's integral (I suspect he proved it with his master theorem). I persume that
$$I_n(a)=(\text{Product of something})I_n(0)$$
with that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\text{Product of something} )=\frac{(1-a)(1-aq)\cdots }{(1-aq^{-s})(1-a q^{1-s})\cdots}$
However, I have yet solved the functional formula in $(4)$

Did you mean $$I_n(a)=\int_0^{\infty} x^{s-1} \left(\frac{(1+ax)\cdots (1+ax q^{n-1})}{(1+x) \cdots (1+x q^n)}\right), dx $$ instead of $$I_n(a)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{1+x}\left(\frac{(1+ax)\cdots (1+ax q^{n-1})}{(1+x) \cdots (1+x q^n)}\right), dx $$ in $(1)$?

Yes, thanks for the reminder

I also noted that if you differentiate the integral with respect to $a$, then by the Leibniz integral rule, we get the integral: $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \prod_{k=0}^n \frac{x^{s-1}}{x q^k + 1} dx $$ which can also be written as $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{(n+1)(s-1)}}{(-x; q)_{n+1}} dx $$ where $(a; q)_n$ is the q-Pochhammer symbol. I am unfamiliar with their integration..but I have a suspicion that you could do partial fractions and obtain a closed form for $I'_n(a)$

I forgot to add, the expression for $I'_n(a)$ is missing a factor of $a^{n-1} q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$. Also from your post it seems that $I'_n(a)$ does indeed have a closed form

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{1+x}\left(\frac{(1+ax)\cdots (1+ax q^{n-1})}{(1+qx) \cdots (1+x q^n)}\right)\, dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi s}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^ka^k q^{\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}\left\{\frac{(1-q^{1-s-k})\cdots (1-q^{n-s-k})}{(1-q)\cdots (1-q^k)(1-q)\cdots (1-q^{n-k})}\right\}$$
This is done by expanding the polynomial $(1+ax)(1+axq)\cdots(1+axq^{n-1})$. However, I have not yet succeed writing the problem as a product
